# Partly negative period between 2 dates with NodaTime

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I use NodaTime library to get period between two days, but sometimes I get partly negative period between two dates:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var end = start.AddDays(7).AddMinutes(-1);

//6 days, 24 hours and -1 minutes
var period = Period.Between(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(start), LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(end));
```

How can I prevent such behavior? 
At this moment I already have found one solution:

```
//6 days, 23 hours and 59 minutes, but no weeks, months, years
var duration = period.ToDuration();
```

But duration object is not contrain weeks, months, years and so on.

Comment: Yikes. That's a bug. I'm not sure what's causing it yet, so I can't work out how to avoid it - but I'll have a look as soon as I can, fix it, and release a new patched version (2.0.2).

Comment: Filed https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/824

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for such fast reaction!

Comment: Okay, found and fixed - but I'm not sure there's a simple workaround, to be honest... nothing I can think of to add as an answer (other than to use 1.3.4 instead, which doesn't have the bug). I'm hoping to get 2.0.2 out sometime in the next week to address this. Not sure the best course of action for this post though...

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for you help!
I think it's ok to post answer with information of new version (even if this version is not release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Update to Noda Time 2.0.2.

This was a bug in 2.0.0 and 2.0.1 of Noda Time. Brief testing suggests it wasn't an issue in earlier versions.

The problem was due to an optimization when trying to obtain the time parts of a period between two `LocalDateTime` values. Consider finding the difference between these values using all units:

```
start: 2017-05-22T12:00:00
end:   2017-05-25T11:30:00
```

We'd start by finding the days portion: 2 days (not 3, because that would overshoot). That would leave us finding the time units between:

```
updated-start: 2017-05-24T12:00:00
end:           2017-05-25T11:30:00
```

When trying to find the number of hours, it would first find the number of days between the two dates, then multiply by 24, and then the number of hours between the results - so we'd end up with 24 hours, which then overshot by 30 minutes.

The fix for this was basically an overhaul of `Period` - see [PR 825](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/pull/825) and [PR 826](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/pull/826). PR 825 was then cherry-picked into the 2.0.x branch, and 2.0.2 was released on May 22nd 2017.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jon Skeet, this bug will be fixed in 2.0.2 version of NodaTime.